# Entity Framework is very slow while SSMS is instant

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For some strange reason when I am querying a table in Visual Studio 2017 it takes too long and users are frustrated. It is returning 25k records.
 This same piece of code on ssms is instant.

This is my EF code.

```
   var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
   sw.Start();
   var map  = ce.myTable.ToList();
   sw.Stop();
   var se = sw.Elapsed.Seconds;
```

It takes 24 seconds via a stopwatch count

This same code taken from the EF query takes 1 second if i run it on my SSMS.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[RefDataChangeEventId] AS [RefDataChangeEventId], 
    [Extent1].[InvestNum] AS [InvestNum], 
    [Extent1].[OldInvestNum] AS [OldInvestNum], 
    [Extent1].[InvestName] AS [InvestName], 
    [Extent1].[InvestAddr] AS [InvestAddr], 
    [Extent1].[InvestCity] AS [InvestCity], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNum] AS [PhoneNum], 
    [Extent1].[ContactPerson] AS [ContactPerson], 
    [Extent1].[CustodialBankName] AS [CustodialBankName], 
    [Extent1].[CustodialBankCityState] AS [CustodialBankCityState], 
    [Extent1].[RoutingNum] AS [RoutingNum], 
    [Extent1].[CheckingAcctNum] AS [CheckingAcctNum], 
    [Extent1].[EscrowAcctNum] AS [EscrowAcctNum], 
    [Extent1].[EscrowBankName] AS [EscrowBankName], 
    [Extent1].[EscrowBankCityState] AS [EscrowBankCityState], 
    [Extent1].[InvestAgencyType] AS [InvestAgencyType], 
    [Extent1].[ConformUsingInvestNumFlag] AS [ConformUsingInvestNumFlag], 
    [Extent1].[InvestAcctingRptStyleType] AS [InvestAcctingRptStyleType], 
    [Extent1].[SchedBalCutoffType] AS [SchedBalCutoffType], 
    [Extent1].[PmtType] AS [PmtType], 
    [Extent1].[PrinRemitType] AS [PrinRemitType], 
    [Extent1].[IntRemitType] AS [IntRemitType], 
    [Extent1].[DlvyType] AS [DlvyType], 
    [Extent1].[SellerServicerNum] AS [SellerServicerNum], 
    [Extent1].[GovtFlag] AS [GovtFlag], 
    [Extent1].[BondREOType] AS [BondREOType], 
    [Extent1].[NegAmortFlag] AS [NegAmortFlag], 
    [Extent1].[MultiFamilyFlag] AS [MultiFamilyFlag], 
    [Extent1].[SrvType] AS [SrvType], 
    [Extent1].[AcqFlag] AS [AcqFlag], 
    [Extent1].[RemitDt] AS [RemitDt], 
    [Extent1].[RemitDayType] AS [RemitDayType], 
    [Extent1].[RemitStyleType] AS [RemitStyleType], 
    [Extent1].[MajorFlag] AS [MajorFlag], 
    [Extent1].[CoIssueFlag] AS [CoIssueFlag], 
    [Extent1].[ParticipationConduitFlag] AS [ParticipationConduitFlag], 
    [Extent1].[HedgeableInvFlagBit] AS [HedgeableInvFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[TreasBankPortfolioFlagBit] AS [TreasBankPortfolioFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[TreasBankPortfolioToCHLFlagBit] AS [TreasBankPortfolioToCHLFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[UnsaleableInvFlagBit] AS [UnsaleableInvFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[PoolableInvFlagBit] AS [PoolableInvFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[AcctingInvFlagBit] AS [AcctingInvFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[InvAvailForRepoFlagBit] AS [InvAvailForRepoFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[RepurchaseInvAvailForRepoFlagBit] AS [RepurchaseInvAvailForRepoFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[MtgVenturesFlagBit] AS [MtgVenturesFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[CSCPortfolioFlagBit] AS [CSCPortfolioFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[REOFlagBit] AS [REOFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[OTCFlagBit] AS [OTCFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[LegalOwnerId] AS [LegalOwnerId], 
    [Extent1].[ManagedByCd] AS [ManagedByCd], 
    [Extent1].[HFSHFICd] AS [HFSHFICd], 
    [Extent1].[NewInvestNumFlag] AS [NewInvestNumFlag], 
    [Extent1].[LoanExistFlagBit] AS [LoanExistFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[SBOFlagBit] AS [SBOFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[MICompanyFlagBit] AS [MICompanyFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[PremPrivInvTypeCd] AS [PremPrivInvTypeCd], 
    [Extent1].[SecuritizeHFIFlagBit] AS [SecuritizeHFIFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[ExecutionTypeDesc] AS [ExecutionTypeDesc], 
    [Extent1].[InvestContractName] AS [InvestContractName], 
    [Extent1].[SrvInvestGrpType] AS [SrvInvestGrpType], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedOn] AS [UpdatedOn], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], 
    [Extent1].[ActiveFlagBit] AS [ActiveFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[DataDt] AS [DataDt], 
    [Extent1].[BegDt] AS [BegDt], 
    [Extent1].[EndDt] AS [EndDt], 
    [Extent1].[CurrentFlagBit] AS [CurrentFlagBit], 
    [Extent1].[LTSBFlag] AS [LTSBFlag], 
    [Extent1].[InsurerType] AS [InsurerType], 
    [Extent1].[RESIInvestNumFlag] AS [RESIInvestNumFlag], 
    [Extent1].[GLCompany] AS [GLCompany], 
    [Extent1].[GLCostCenter] AS [GLCostCenter], 
    [Extent1].[GLProfitCenter] AS [GLProfitCenter], 
    [Extent1].[HFSTransferFlagBit] AS [HFSTransferFlagBit]
    FROM [dbo].[myTable] AS [Extent1]
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: MySQL != Sql Server... that said, I have never been a fan of the various database "wrapper" frameworks, but my guess would be EF is doing a lot of work loading the results into it's data structures. Also, is the EF code and SSMS query running on the same machine, or is one "closer" to the database?

Comment: could it be the initial connection? did you try to do it twice in code and compare first with second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not using all 25k records, avoid the `ToList()` right away and do your filtering/paging, then do a `ToList()` on the result of that and return it. Grabbing the whole table and doing a `ToList()` on it for 25k records would definitely take some time so if you can cut down the number of records for the purposes of your query (are you actually returning all 25k?) that would help.

There is a lot of good info for performance tuning here as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, taking 25k records is a lot. In SSMS you are just querying the data and showing it, in Entity Framework you're making entity objects of the said table. If you really need to query 25k records, you can try to split the data, query 100 or so records at a time.